# Cannot use JsonPath libraries in browser due to "unsafe-eval" CSP directive

Tags: browser, eval, content-security-policy, jsonpath

I want to use some JsonPath library in browser, but they all relying on `eval()`/`Function()` that get caught with unsafe-eval by [CSP](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#directive-script-src). And any other workarounds/3rd party libraries like [static-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-eval)/[safe-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval) also all get caught with the same console error. Does anyone know of any other potential workarounds to resolve this unsafe-eval issue besides allowing the unsafe-eval csp directive?

Comment: How about https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath or https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath

Comment: @wp78de thanks we've looked at them before, similar issues :(

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I found was an old fork of [JSONPath-Plus](https://github.com/erithmetic/JSONPath) that attempted to create a non-eval version of the library. Here's the [Pull Request](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath/pull/4), however, this was never merged (fully) because of some merge issues and performance issues.

I imagine performance would be a problem for other non-eval implementations as well, and that's why we have non, at least to my knowledge.